# get max ID row from individual rows in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group

I Have data like below with multiple rows with same data which can be identified by ID.

[image]

I Need the data like below. Get only individual max ID value for every set of duplicate records with can be done by taking individual max ID

[image]

Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you

```
create table #sample (type char(1), date datetime, Id bigint)
insert into #sample values('A', '5/22/2019 4:33', 1065621)
insert into #sample values('A', '5/22/2019 4:33', 1065181)
insert into #sample values('A', '5/22/2019 4:33', 1064212)
insert into #sample values('B', '11/7/2017 1:07', 540180)
insert into #sample values('B', '11/7/2017 1:07', 540179)
insert into #sample values('B', '11/7/2017 1:07', 540177)

select * from #sample

select [type], [date], max(id)
from #sample
group by [type], [date]

select distinct [type], [date], max(id) over(partition by  [type], [date] )
from #sample

Drop table #sample
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter with a subquery. Assuming that your table's columns are called `id`, `date` and `col`, that would be:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.col = (select max(t1.col) from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id)
```

For performance, consider an index on `(id, col)`.

Answer (score 1):

An efficient method -- with the right index -- is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.individual = (select max(t2.individual) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

The right index is on `(id, individual)`.