# Get max ID row from individual rows in SQK Server with only 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like below with multiple rows with same data which can be identified by ID.

```
A   2784762
A   2788523
A   2789063
B   3423390
B   3423396
```

I need the data like below. Get only individual max ID value for every set of duplicate records with can be done by taking individual max ID

```
A   2789063
B   3423396
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `MAX()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [get max ID row from individual rows in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064897/get-max-id-row-from-individual-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: How is this different from your previous question?

Comment: previous one has 3 columns to drill down the query but it has only 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

Use `MAX` function to achieve this:

```
SELECT COL1,MAX(COL2)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COL1
```

Instead of **COL1,COL2** use your **Table Column Names** and **Table** use your **Table Name**.